# How do I use a value inside a def outside a def

Tags: python

I'm wondering how to call a value inside a def, to outside
eg

```
def location():
  ##Bunch of other code
  key = 'true'

if key == 'true':
  print('You may pass')
```

Current this code returns undefined_variable key or something like that.

My aim is to draw out the value of key.

Edit: if key == 'true'

Thks Julien I know the difference but just forgot to add the quotation marks.

Comment: you can't. Either use global variables, or return the value

Comment: besides, you seem to confuse `true`, `'true'` and `True` as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `return`:

```
def location():
  ##Bunch of other code
  key = 'true'
  return key
key = location()
if key=='true':
  print('You may pass')
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wanted to return multiple values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks to set a local variable.

```
def location(callback):
    ##Bunch of other code
    key = 'true'
    callback(key)

def someFunc(key):
   if key == true:
      print('You may pass')

location(someFunc)
```

Comment: Why do you need to def 's for this, it looks complex (haha.)

Comment: I was adding another solution to the list. Already the first person to comment on this suggested making a global variable or returning a value.